# InputType in EditText changes the gravity of rtl text

Tags: android

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="#E6E6E6"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="סיסמא"
    android:id="@+id/etLoginPassword"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

When i change `android:inputType`, The `TextHint` it 'thrown' to the left. When i change the gravity to 'right', it returns to where it needs to be (Hebrew). However, i want the passwords (text written in EditText) gravity to be 'left' (The password is should be written with English characters). How can i overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex Goft you cannot have separate gravity for hint and text in a EditText.They both can have left or right gravity but hint having right gravity and text having left gravity is not possible

Here is the similar question about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461205/edittext-center-hint-but-have-entered-text-start-from-top)

Answer (score 7):

Try doing this

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Comment: i want text hint to be aligned to the right and the text written to be aligned left

Answer (score 0):

Please add gravity and textalignment attribute.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="#E6E6E6"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="סיסמא"
        android:id="@+id/etLoginPassword"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="left"/>
```